# best solution to server side magazine application

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm going to working in a iOS mobile app for magazine to show weekly magazines and the latest news. The client also needs me to implement the server side, but he will responsible for add the data to be displayed to the users.

My Question is, What about if I use Parse.com as my server to hold all the data? Is Parse a good solution for a such magazine app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't ask questions like that on Stack Overflow, that's why you're getting down voted. But to answer you, yes, I've had some experience with Parse.com, and they make it extremely simple to store data, and query the database, and there are a lot of tutorial videos and sample codes on their website.
Convert images to objects of `PFFile`, and point to them in one of your tables. If you don't know how to do that, check out [this tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/saving-images).

However, if you're uploading complete 'magazines' as PDF-files or something similar, not just an image of the cover, then you might have to look for other options as I think the maximum upload file size is something around 10mb.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rheven, I wanted to know the best solution to me so I had to asked this silly question :). Any way thank you

Comment: Also I don't think we will use PDF because the app is for iPhone.
but If I used Parse and we published the app, the client has to log in Parse account to enter new news and articles in the tables of DB right?

Comment: @HossamGhareeb The general idea of the question is probably fine, but it doesn't seem like you've done any background search. If you had asked the question more like a comparison between two options, giving a few pros and cons for the two, then it would look like you were asking a more technical question.

Comment: but If I used Parse and we published the app, the client has to log in Parse account to enter new news and articles in the tables of DB right? So the users can see it

Comment: @HossamGhareeb That depends on what you want. If all the information you are storing in Parse is going to be available to everyone using the app, then there's no reason for them to have usernames and passwords. You can simply say "database, fetch me the data I want", and it will. But if you want different users to see different data, then you would have to use a login system, which Parse can provide too. But no, you don't have to.

Comment: When you are dealing with Parse.com connections from your iOS app, then you are writing the general credentials in your `AppDelegate.m`, letting everyone query the database without logging in. Watch a couple of the tutorials here: https://parse.com/tutorials , and you'll see how easy it is.